# Backbone: how to get and display just one model data in a view via router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes, single-page-application, backbone-routing

I have created a very basic backbone app, to understand how it works.

In the router, I just wanna display just 1 model, i.e. a user, not the whole collection, by passing an id in the url, how to do that?

For example, I'd like to do `someapp.com/app/#user/2`, and this would display just user no2 details.

Please see my work in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XgZzG/2/)

```
// router
var ViewsRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    '': 'viewOne',
    'one': 'viewOne',
    'two': 'viewTwo',
    'user/:id': 'user'
  },

  viewOne: function() {
    var view = new TheViewOne({ model: new TheModel });
  },

  viewTwo: function() {
    var view = new UserView({ model: new TheModel });
  },

  user: function(id) {
    // how to get just 1 user with the corresponding id passed as argument
    // and display it???
  }
});
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/coding-idiot/BackboneCRUD

I've written a complete Backbone CRUD with no backend stuff for beginners. Below is the [part](https://github.com/coding-idiot/BackboneCRUD/blob/master/nn.js) where we get the user from the collection and show/render it.

**View**

```
  var UserEditView = Backbone.View.extend({
         render: function(options) {
             if (options && options.id) {
                 var template = _.template($("#user-edit-template").html(), {
                     user: userCollection.get(options.id)
                 });
                 this.$el.html(template);
             } else {
                 var template = _.template($("#user-edit-template").html(), {
                     user: null
                 });
                 // console.log(template);
                 this.$el.html(template);
             }
             return this;
         },
```

**Router**

```
router.on('route:editUser', function(id) {
     console.log("Show edit user view : " + id);
     var userEditView = new UserEditView({
         el: '.content'
     });
     userEditView.render({
         id: id
     });
 });
```

**Update**

Particularly, sticking to your code, the router will look something like this :

```
user: function(id) {
     var view = new UserView({ model: userCollection.get(id) });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. 1 thing though. I wanna do this inside the router's definition not outside, and your code is outside, and `Router` in general is still confusing. I don't want `router.on(route:...)`... too advanced for me, but I want `user: function(id) {}` defined inside the `Router` object. Btw, I'm new with Backbone and this `Router` concept is a bit hard to grasp for me, so take it easy on me :).

Comment: var userEditView = new UserEditView();
     userEditView.render({
         id: id
     });

Just use this in your router. Edited my answer to provide a better insight.

Comment: sorry I forgot to accept it. I usually accept answers but I was very happy so it slipped out of my mind... :)